# Skip certain calculated values (not cells themselves) in an AVERAGE or STDEV Excel formula based on a criterion

Tags: excel

I have a series of paired measurements (two for each sample). I need to calculate the mean for each pair and then the general mean based on those pairwise averaged values, but I can only include those pairwise means that don't exceed a certain threshold.

I'm trying to work out an excel formula for the general mean that takes into account all of the above, without having to create additional rows/columns.

Now, the formula

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ABS(A1-A2)<$C$1,AVERAGE(A1,A2)),IF(ABS(A7-A8)<$C$1,AVERAGE(A7,A8)), ... )
```

... doesn't do the job because it replaces with zeros those pairwise means that exceed the threshold (value of $C$1), while they just need to be skipped. "AVERAGEIF" doesn't work because it doesn't accept non-contiguous ranges (at least when they are entered as such), using "INDIRECT" to build non-contiguous ranges doesn't help either because it doesn't accept formulas. Any help appreciated.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using helper columns. In fact , 9 times out of 10 the performance is much better. In addition your spreadsheet becomes easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Not using helper column here is making formula look ugly but will give you the desired result. Have a try.

```
=AVERAGE(IF(CHOOSE({1;2;3},A1-A2,A4-A5,A7-A8)<C1,CHOOSE({1;2;3},AVERAGE(A1,A2),AVERAGE(A4,A5),AVERAGE(A7,A8))))
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

See image to see the difference in the result from above formula and formula in question that is yielding incorrect result as you mentioned.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. A useful reminder of the CHOOSE function

Answer (score 0):

This is where Excel has some mysterious behaviour I think.

My first thought was to make each if statement return "" if the condition wasn't satisfied

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ABS(A1-A2)<$C$1,AVERAGE(A1,A2),""),IF(ABS(A7-A8)<$C$1,AVERAGE(A7,A8),""))
```

but this just gives you an error.

However, if you make it return a reference to an empty cell (say B1) it works fine

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ABS(A1-A2)<$C$1,AVERAGE(A1,A2),$B$1),IF(ABS(A7-A8)<$C$1,AVERAGE(A7,A8),$B$1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a load. Very elegant indeed. I was stuck with the empty string...

Comment: You're welcome! Might be wise to set a validation rule on that cell (B1) so that nothing gets accidentally put into it ;-)